# Android Studio wrong breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-debug

I try to debug some code, but Android Studio debugger behaves strange today.

It accepts breakpoints like randomly. Where there is no executable code preview sometimes shows there is. And for executable lines preview says that the code is not executable.

[image]

I tried to sync, clean, rebuild, invalidate cashes/restart, but notheng had effect.

Has someone faced this problem before and whta is the solution?

Comment: what is the line before it

Comment: I've just updated the screenshot to show the problem widly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rebuild project might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

that is an invalid break point that shows when the breakpoint is set on a commented or non-executable line indicating that such breakpoint would not be hit.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but why debugger considers the line with only curly brace as executable, but line with setting a variable value as non-executable?

Comment: it's just said that it can be not executed because it's inside an if. The condition would be true or false so that line can be executed when it's true and not when it's false.